# How to get path of method in c# completely?

Tags: c#

We need to transfer some method path to another project. Is there any way to get quickly method path?
For example I have a `GetForContractInfoList()` that is placed in `App.Api.NetFinanceInfoService` namespace. I want to get this path as a string by Right_Click on it:

```
App.Api.NetFinanceInfoService.GetForContractInfoList()
```

How can I get this completely?

Comment: Do you mean in the IDE?

Comment: Yes in the IDE @David

Comment: When you say "to another project" do you mean "to a different namespace"? What are you going to do with the fully qualified name once you have it?

Comment: I need to copy method path to document for report

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]You can get it by Reflection.

```
var methodInfo = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
string fullName = methodInfo.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + methodInfo.Name;
```

Comment: no midhan I want for example right click on method and get path

Comment: in ide right click on that class and select resolve to resolve the namespace.here you will get the namespace

Comment: else genarate code map you will get entire information about that method

Comment: This solution doesn't give me any path